# Función no devuelve el número en común o el número más pequeño entre arrays

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con un ejercicio para que me pasen los test, me piden:

> `numeroEnComun(array1, array2)`
> × Debería retornar el número en común entre los arrays que recibe por parámetro, en caso de no haber número en común, devolver el número más pequeño (3 ms)
> × Debería retornar el número más chico en caso de que no haya números en común entre ambos arrays (2 ms)

La consigna es esta:

```js
function numeroEnComun(array1, array2) {

// Entre los dos array's que recibe la funcion por parametro
// Buscar y retornar el valor en comun entre ellos
```

y mi código este:

```js
var result = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
   for(var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++){
       if(array1[i] === array2[j]){
        var result = array1[i]
       if(array1[i] !== array2[j]){
           min = Math.min(array1[i])
           min2 = Math.min(array2[j])
           if(min < min2){
               return min
           } else {
               return min2
           }
       }
   }
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: ¿Que pasa si hay más de un número en común? ¿Qué retornas: un array con todos los números en común o el primer número en común que encuentres?

Comment: el primer numero en comun

Comment: Te faltó algo importante: ¿cuál es tu problema?

Comment: El problema es que me estaria devolviendo esto :  Expected: 15
    Received: 0 y esto Expected: 2
    Received: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola en tu función tienes el problema de que después de comprobar si los dos números son iguales, encadenas otro if para ver si no son iguales, pero este solo se ejecutará si el if anterior es cierto, con lo cual no tiene sentido. Tienes que hacer lo siguiente, primero comprobar si los números son iguales, si es así, haces un return con el valor que has encontrado y aquí termina la función. Si no hay números iguales, la función continúa, entonces como ya sabes que no los hay, simplemente extraes el número menor y lo devuelves. Para ello lo más fácil es pasarle toda la matriz al Math.min de la siguiente forma `Math.min[...array]`, así te devolverá el número menor de una tacada en lugar de tener que recorrerla. Te dejo el código con un par de ejemplos. Un saludo!!!

```js
function numeroEnComun(array1, array2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
            if (array1[i] === array2[j]) {
                return array1[i];
            }
        }
    }
    let min = Math.min(...array1)
    let min2 = Math.min(...array2)
    if (min < min2) {return min;}
    return min2;
}
var array1 = [100, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 18];
var array2 = [110, 12, 150, 27, 60, 18];
console.log(numeroEnComun(array1, array2));
var array1 = [100, 20, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 180];
var array2 = [110, 10, 150, 27, 60, 18];
console.log(numeroEnComun(array1, array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function numeroEnComun(array1, array2) {
    
    
      let miNum = array1.filter((element1) => array2.includes(element1));
      
      if (miNum.length !== 0) {
        return Number(miNum);

      } else if (miNum.length === 0) {
          let nuevoArray = [...array2, array1];
          nuevoArray = nuevoArray.flat();

          let miMin = Math.min(...nuevoArray);

          
          return miMin;
      }
 numeroEnComun([10, 20, 24], [2, 20, 10]);        
 numeroEnComun([10, 20, 24], [2, 20, 1]);
```

Answer (score -3):

Prueba esto:

```
    double numeroEnComun(double[] array1, double[] array2 )
{
    var result = 0;
    double min=999999, min1=99999, min2=99999;

    for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++)
        {
            if(array1[i] == array2[j])
            {
                result = array1[i];
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                min1 = Math.min(array1[i]);
                min2 = Math.min(array2[j]);
                if(min1 <= min2 && min1< min)
                {
                    min =min1;
                }
                else if(min2 <= min1 && min2 < min)
                {
                    min = min2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  return min;
}
```

Comment: ¿`double []`? La pregunta del usuario esta en `javascript`, no en `java`. Entiendo que no especifica `javascript` en las etiquetas, pero se puede sobreentender por la estructura de `function ...` y la omisión de los tipos de datos.